# Should I need to dispose System.Threading.Timer after completing my task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm using this code to execute my code once with the 10-second delay on a separate thread.

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(e=> {
    //My code
    timer.Dispose();
    },null,10000,System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

I want to ask that if I need to use `timer.Dispose()` after completing my task or the timer will be released automatically.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should always dispose the Timer.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> When a timer is no longer needed, use the Dispose method to free the
>   resources held by the timer. Note that callbacks can occur after the
>   Dispose() method overload has been called, because the timer queues
>   callbacks for execution by thread pool threads. You can use the
>   Dispose(WaitHandle) method overload to wait until all callbacks have
>   completed.

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` is different from `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: Correct, just updated my answer, however the pattern still applies. Dispose everytime you don't need it.